# regular expression to remove a space

Tags: java, regex

I need a way to remove only the first space found in a string and then put the string in an array. For example

```
hello there. Hey.
```

I want that to be split like `[hello][there. Hey]`. I tried with

```
String [] s = str.split(" ")
```

by that will naturally remove all the spaces and create several strings. i just need 2. Can you please tell me how to do that ? Ether by regular expression or another way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String [] s = str.split (" ", 2);` should do the trick, documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

You may also want to consider using `\s+` as the regex - it may split the string more intelligently.

Comment: In my case i have an instruction and then a name of file . I want the instruction to be at position 0 of the array and the name whatever that is to be at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression for this isn't necessarily your best option.

Find the first space using position() (whatever the java method is), and then use substring() from the beginning of the string to that position, and again from that position to the end of the string.