# remove specific spaces using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I a not a reg ex chap. So I would really appreciate if some one can help me this this.

[regular expression to remove a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138502/regular-expression-to-remove-a-space)

[javascript regular expression remove complete words only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244152/javascript-regular-expression-remove-complete-words-only)

[Regular Expression to replace non alpha characters with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220172/regular-expression-to-replace-non-alpha-characters-with-spaces)

[regular expression to remove white spaces in a line and extract specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154768/regular-expression-to-remove-white-spaces-in-a-line-and-extract-specific-columns)

above link do not help me

however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524270/regular-expression-for-removing-one-space) seems close

I have this string

```
<tr class="trClass"    >  <td class="tdClss"  > adasd   
<span class=classA  >     as  da  "sads "sd</span> </td> </tr>
```

There are three classes in the above html string.

1. "trClass"
2. "tdClss"
3. classA

The spaces after class name is undetermined

Weather class names will be in quote or not is undetermined

**I want to remove the spaces before > sign**

**What regular expression will match this condition?**

---

my code

```
 public static string Flatten(string inputString)
    {
        // remove line breaks
        string rawInput = inputString.RemoveLineBreaks().Trim();

        string filteredInput = Regex.Match(rawInput, "<tr.+?>.*</tr>").ToString();

        if (filteredInput.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
        {
            // remove space between end and start tags
            filteredInput = Regex.Replace(filteredInput, ">.+?<", delegate(Match match)
                {
                    string v = match.ToString();
                    return ">" + v.Substring(1, v.Length - 2).Trim() + "<";
                });

            // remove space between attribute and closing tags
            filteredInput = Regex.Replace(filteredInput, "\t>", delegate(Match match)
            {
                //string v = match.ToString();
                return ">";
            });


            return filteredInput;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid HTML Table Row!";
        }

    }
```

Comment: You say that one link came close. How close? Where's the code that you're currently using to do this?

Comment: just need to know What regular expression will match this condition?

Comment: Just need to see what effort you've made in working this out yourself aside from using Google.

Comment: alright.. i'll post my code

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I added my code. the "// remove space between attribute and closing tags" part doesn't work. It never matches.

Comment: Start with reading some tutorials http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-file  | http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84524/deep-c-regular-expressions-8211-the-director8217s-cut/ | http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: alright. solved. http://petdance.com/perl/class/regex-match.htm helped,me

Comment: wow.. people just enjoy clinking on that downvote button.

Comment: best thing ever: http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: @bilalfazlani ahahah.. you just need to get used to it. Especially when you post a question with incomplete informations. +1 to uplift your burden. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on exactly what you've posted, the pattern `+>` would match the condition you specified. In other words, you are looking for one or more space (`+`) followed by a closing angle bracket (`>`). You can use a `Regex.Replace` call and pass `>` as the replacement for that pattern.

Be forewarned:  Manipulating HTML with regex can be perilous. If you have any unencoded `>` in your string, then it might still be matched by the above pattern. For what you've shown above, I suspect you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply load this into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) using [XDocument.Parse(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) it will take care of this for you.

```
var test = XDocument.Parse("<tr class=\"trClass\"    >  <td class=\"tdClss\"  > adasd   <span class=\"classA\"  >     as  da  \"sads \"sd</span> </td> </tr>");
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

You don't need to use regular expressions. This gives you the below:

```
<tr class="trClass">
    <td class="tdClss"> adasd   <span class="classA">     as  da  "sads "sd</span></td>
</tr>
```